# NoSuchMethod exception using jaxb 3.0.0

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm currently trying to upgrade to JAXB-XJC 3.0.0-M4 version and my project doesn't compile anymore. I'm currently getting this error log with `NoSuchMethodError`

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.tools.xjc.model.CElementPropertyInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/tools/xjc/model/CElementPropertyInfo$CollectionMode;Lcom/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/core/ID;Ljavax/activation/MimeType;Lcom/sun/xml/xsom/XSComponent;Lcom/sun/tools/xjc/model/CCustomizations;Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;Z)V
1>  at com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.xew.XmlElementWrapperPlugin.runInternal(XmlElementWrapperPlugin.java:451)
1>  at com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.xew.config.AbstractConfigurablePlugin.run(AbstractConfigurablePlugin.java:263)
1>  at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:262)
1>  at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCBase._doXJC(XJCBase.java:844)
1>  at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCBase.doXJC(XJCBase.java:787)
1>  at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCBase.execute(XJCBase.java:686)
1>  at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJC2Task.execute(XJC2Task.java:25)
1>  at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:67)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
1>  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
1>  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
1>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:830)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
1>  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
1>
```

Anyone has any idea or experience with this?

Comment: This occurs if you have incompatible libraries in your classpath. Make sure that your `jaxb-xjc.jar` and `jaxb-impl` are both having same version.

Comment: @Amitkumar they are both at 3.0.0-M4 version

Comment: Is it a spring project ? If yes please share `pom.xml` file. Which version of Java are you using ? What's the version you are trying to upgrade from to `JAXB-XJC 3.0.0-M4`. Please share all the relevant details.

Comment: it's not a spring project. We are using java 1.8, and we currently have jaxb-xjc 2.3.0 and jaxb-core 2.3.0 and trying to upgrade both to 3.0.0-M4

Comment: `jaxb-xew-plugin` doesn't support 3.0.0 yet, there's an open issue here: https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin/issues/66